# How to drop rows that are composed of a series of specifc values

Tags: python, pandas

So I have the following df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['John', 1.0,    2.0, 3.0],
        ['Mary', 0.0, np.nan,  ""],
        ['Chad', 0.0, np.nan, 1.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'])
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
```

I need to drop every column that contains only: 0.0 or NaN or "". In other words, on the example above I want to drop only Mary's row. Chad's row wouldn't be dropped since it has the 1.0 on the third column. But I got stuck.

I have been trying to do it this way:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df[:] == 0) | (df[:] == '') | (df[:] == np.nan)])
```

But it returns this error:

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your code :)

`df.replace({0:np.nan, '': np.nan}).dropna(how='all')`

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to simply use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), since all `0.0` , `NaN` and `""` evaluate to `False`:

```
df[df.any(1)]

       Value1  Value2 Value3
Name                       
John     1.0     2.0      3
Chad     0.0     NaN      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted logic - get all rows without values specified in list:

```
df = df[~df.isin([np.nan,'',0]).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
      Value1  Value2 Value3
Name                       
John     1.0     2.0      3
Chad     0.0     NaN      1
```